# putting an icon next to two paragraphs. Icon should be vertically in center right next to the paragraphs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons, row

I want to put an icon next to two paragraphs in a way that the icon is exactly at the center (vertically) on the left hand side of the two paragraphs. This is what I want:

[image: To be]

This is what I have:

[image: As is]

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"> <span>
      Promo Code
    </span>
    <icon type="Success filled"></icon>
    <p class="text-success">PlayerRegistrationPromotion Applied</p>
    <p>
      $ in credits available</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S:
Please note that the spelling and sentences are dummy data and don't matter. The styling here is important. So what's the best way to get the wanted result?

Comment: Please supply your associated CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

https://codepen.io/polinq/pen/abzBYoy

Clarification: display: flex on inner will group the elements in two columns.By default, flex-direction will be row so you will have these element in one row. 
I also added another div (inner-two) so it separates the text 'PlayerRegistrationPromotion Applied' and the text about the credit. If you were to remove it the text will be next to each other, not in separate rows.

I hope it is all clear!

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"> <span>
      Promo Code
    </span>
    <div class="inner">

        <icon type="Success filled"><img src="http://placekitten.com/60/90" alt=""></icon> 
      <div class="inner-2">
    <p class="text-success">PlayerRegistrationPromotion Applied</p>
    <p>
      $ in credits available</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.inner {
  display: flex;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap(?). One way you could do this is by having the 'Promo Code' text on one line that spans the full width and then with the next row having the checkmark icon in a couple columns and the additional text in the remaining columns.

Something like this might get you started:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">Promo Code</div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center"><icon type="Success filled"></icon></div>
  <div class="col-9"><p class="text-success">PlayerRegistrationPromotion Applied</p><p>$ in credits available</p></div>
</div>
```